# How to use a column value in an Ecto query?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following table:

```
                                       Table "public.cards"
    Column     |            Type             |                     Modifiers
---------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id            | integer                     | not null default nextval('cards_id_seq'::regclass)
 question      | text                        | not null
 answer        | text                        | not null
 grade         | integer                     |
 last_trained  | timestamp without time zone |
 next_train    | integer                     | not null
 times_trained | integer                     | not null
 url           | character varying(255)      |
 user_id       | integer                     |
 inserted_at   | timestamp without time zone | not null
 updated_at    | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

I trying to construct a query in Ecto corresponding to this:

```
SELECT * FROM cards
WHERE date_part('day', now()-last_trained) > next_train;
```

Comment: Checkout the `fragment` function of Ecto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Ecto.Query.API.fragment/1](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#fragment/1)

```
import Ecto.Query

...
from(c in Card, where: fragment("date_part('day', now()-last_trained) > next_train")
```